# Specifying the position of a label in geom_text

Tags: r

I created a barplot and later added geom_text. I would like to make labels start at the bottom of each bar, I tried to use position vjust and hjust, also specify y = 0, but they didn't work, because labels have different lengths. I would like to solve it by specyfing geom_text arguments if possible. That's part of how my plot looks:

[image]

I want to make every label start at the same height, or just at the bottom of each bar

Code similar to my original

```
xxx <- sample(letters,1000, replace = T)
xxx <- data.frame(x=xxx)
text <- c(rep(c("b","adsasdasasd"),13))
library(tidyverse)
xxx %>%
  count(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,n))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(x, label = text),y=0, angle=90)
```

Comment: Can you post the code? I suspect you put the `y=0` inside `aes()`, which won't work, but that it will work with `geom_text(aes(x = orig_dest, label = orig_dest), y=0)`

Comment: I tried specify y outside aes but it doesn't work as I want, since it specify the middle point of my label. I'll post code soon

Comment: @Alexlok I posted code

Answer (score 1):

It should work using both `y=0` to specify the position relative to the graph, and `hjust` to specify the position of the text relative to the `y`:

```
library(tidyverse)
xxx <- sample(letters,1000, replace = T)
xxx <- data.frame(x=xxx)
text <- c(rep(c("b","adsasdasasd"),13))

xxx %>%
  count(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,n))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(x, label = text), y=0, hjust="bottom", angle=90)
```

[image: plot with text aligned on x axis]

Comment: I was missing that ,,bottom" argument thanks a lot!